# Which would be appropriate accepts or accept

Tags: grammar, verbs, american-english, british-english, subjunctive-mood

thanks in advance for answering the following question. I am trying to figure out which one would be correct. I am in process of writing documentation on a technical subject and I was asked to replace 'accepts' with 'accept'. But not sure why.

1. Both 'right-click'and 'double-click' accept 2 parameters
2. Both 'right-click'and 'double-click' accepts 2 parameters

-Murali

Comment: The word *both* denotes *two* - plural - so that the verb should also be plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it in steps with this example:

> Alice **likes** apples.
>   Bob **likes** apples.
>   Alice and Bob **like** apples.
>   Both Alice and Bob **like** apples.

I hope it is now clear why the sentence should read

> Both 'right-click' and 'double-click' **accept** 2 parameters.

Comment: Weathervane thank you for the response. So, its same as @smock said, if its singular then accepts, if its plural, then accept. So nothing to do with perspective? like third-person perspective etc?

Comment: That's incorrect. "Accept" follows the typical regular conjugation: (singular) I accept, you accept, he/she accepts; (plural) we accept, you accept, they accept.